# Nested keyof keyof T in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface like this...

```
export interface IMyInterface {
  test1: {
    test1Sub: {
      test1SubSub: string
    }
  },
  test2: {
    test2Sub: {
      test2SubSub: string
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to strongly type the names of the nested levels into a generic function to give TypeScript intellisense something like this which is in a generic class passing in Type T.

```
  getSetting = (level1: keyof T, level2: keyof keyof T) => {
    console.log(level1, level2)
  }
```

Is this possible?  How I have it at the moment it gives me this warning, it works fine for 'test1' but not 'test1Sub;

`settings.getPageSettings('test1', 'test1Sub')`

> Argument of type '"test1Sub"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"toString" | "valueOf" | "toLocaleString"'

Comment: Here's a quick [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WzAMrm). Basically you don't want `keyof keyof` for the sub-level you want `keyof T[K]`... `function getSetting<T extends IMyInterface, K extends keyof T>(level1: K, level2: keyof T[K]) {`

Comment: This is absolutely perfect thank you so much, if you want to write as answer I can approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want `keyof keyof` for the sub-level as this will the the `keys` of each type defined by `keyof IMyInterface`, instead you want `keyof T[K]`

Here's a quick [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WzAMrm).

```
export interface IMyInterface {
  test1: {
    test1Sub: {
      test1SubSub: string
    }
  },
  test2: {
    test2Sub: {
      test2SubSub: string
    }
  }
}

function getSetting<T extends IMyInterface, K extends keyof T>(level1: K, level2: keyof T[K]) {
    console.log(level1, level2)
  }


// usage
const myInterface:IMyInterface ={
  test1: {
    test1Sub: {
      test1SubSub: 'subsub1'
    }
  },
  test2: {
    test2Sub: {
      test2SubSub: 'subsub2'
    }
  }
}

getSetting('test1', 'test1Sub');

getSetting('test2', 'test1Sub');
//                   ^^^^^^^^
// Argument of type '"test1Sub"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"test2Sub"'
```